# PHP Email Array Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, email, explode

Given a list of emails, formated:

```
  "FirstName Last" <email@address.com>, "NewFirst NewLast" <email2@address.com>
```

How can I build this into a string array of Only email addresses (I don't need the names).

Comment: Don’t use regular expressions, use a parser.

Comment: Thanks guys, you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP’s Mailparse extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php) has a [`mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses` function](http://php.net/mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses) you might want to try. Otherwise you should build your own address parser.

Comment: +1 Reinventing the wheel = bad. Reinventing the wheel using regex = worse.

Comment: +1 I got carried away with the regex approach. This seems to be *the* way to do it.

Comment: Or, as read in this function comments, you can use this PEAR package : http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-rfc822.parseaddresslist.php

Answer (score 2):

You could use `preg_match_all` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)):

```
preg_match_all('/<([^>]+)>/', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches); // inspect the resulting array
```

Provided that all addresses are enclosed in `< ... >` there is no need to `explode()` the string `$s`.

---

**EDIT** In response to comments, the regex could be rewritten as `'/<([^@]+@[^>]+)>/'`. Not sure whether this is fail-safe, though :)

---

**EDIT #2** Use a parser for *any* non-trivial data (see the comments below - email address parsing is a bitch). Some errors could, however, be prevented by removing duplicate addresses.

Comment: And, of course, this fails on e-mail addresses like `">"@example.com`. Isn't e-mail great? Not that this expression wouldn't work for every e-mail in practice, *in theory* it's wrong. +1 anyway.

Comment: What if the quoted display name contains `<…>`?

Comment: Your failsafe still fails in theory: `"@>"@example.com` E-mail sucks. Still, I'm liking the effort you're putting into this. You can't really parse e-mail perfectly with a regular expression. At least not a very simple one. I believe there's one floating around that's several hundred characters that does the job. http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html Turns out it's several *thousand* characters.

Comment: Now `"<user-1@example.com>" <user-2@example.com>` will result in two addresses.

Comment: @Gumbo In that case (i.e. name can contain `< ... @ ...>`) you should use a parser :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

 $s = "\"FirstName Last\" <email@address.com>, \"NewFirst NewLast\" <email2@address.com>";

 $emails = array();
 foreach (split(",", $s) as $full)
 {
  preg_match("/.*<([^>]+)/", $full, $email);
  $emails[] = $email[1];
 }

 print_r($emails);
?>
```

Comment: What if the quoted display name contains a comma?